# Which of these situations are a catch?

Tags: rules, cricket

Will the batsman be dismissed as caught is each of the below scenario:

- If the ball hits the arm pad of the batsman and is caught by the fielder.
- If the ball hits the leg pad first, then hits the bat and is finally caught by the fielder.
- If the ball hits the bat first, then hits the umpire and is finally caught by the fielder.
- If the ball hits the bat first, then hits the batting partner and is finally caught by the fielder.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Wikipedia defines caught](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caught) as

> A batsman is out caught if a fielder catches the ball fully within the field of play without it bouncing once the ball has touched the striker's bat or glove holding the bat. If a batsman could be given out caught or by any other method except bowled, 'caught' takes precedence.

[Law 33 of the Laws of cricket](https://www.lords.org/mcc/the-laws-of-cricket/caught) has sub-clauses defining fair-catches, one of which is:

> 33.2.2.3 a fielder catches the ball after it has touched the wicket, an umpire, another fielder, a runner or the other batsman.

So, to answer your various scenarios,

> If the ball hits the arm pad of the batsman and is caught by the fielder.

**No.** This will not be a dismissal as it has neither touched the the batsman's bat nor the glove holding the bat.

> If the ball hits the leg pad first, then hits the bat and is finally caught by the fielder.

**Yes.** This is considered a legal catch and the batsman is dismissed.

> If the ball hits the bat first, then hits the umpire and is finally caught by  fielder.

**Yes.** Refer 33.2.2.3 above.

> If the ball hits the bat first, then hits the batting partner and is finally caught by the fielder.

**Yes.** Refer 33.2.2.3 above.